# Adding user agent scraping API using jsonlite / fromJSON

Tags: r, api, user-agent, jsonlite

I've started receiving 429 errors for the below script. The API I'm scraping requires a user-agent to be specified.

I'm at a loss for how do to specify a user agent header with the package I am using. The attempts I made using `RCurl::getUrl` produced errors as well.

Using `options(HTTPUserAgent = "what google returns when I search my user agent")` did not fix the 429 problem.

API documentation linked below.

https://docs.helium.com/api/blockchain/introduction/#specify-a-user-agent

```
library(jsonlite)

blocks_api <- 'https://api.helium.io/v1/blocks'
blocks <- fromJSON(blocks_api)

endTime <- Sys.Date()
blockMax_api <- paste0(blocks_api,"/height","/?max_time=",endTime)
blockMax_ep <- fromJSON(blockMax_api)
blockMax <- max(blockMax_ep$data$height)

startTime <- Sys.Date() - 1
blockMin_api <- paste0(blocks_api,"/height","/?max_time=",startTime)
blockMin_ep <- fromJSON(blockMin_api)
blockMin <- blockMin_ep$data$height
period_blocks <- blockMax - blockMin

blockTimes <- data.frame()
oraclePrice <- 'https://api.helium.io/v1/oracle/prices'

for(i in blockMin:blockMax){
  block_n <- fromJSON(paste0(blocks_api,"/",i))
  block_n <- as.data.frame(block_n)
  block_n$data.time <- anytime(block_n$data.time)
  block_n <- block_n[,c(2,5,6)]
  oracleBlockPrice <- fromJSON(paste0(oraclePrice,"/",i))
  block_n$HNTprice <- oracleBlockPrice$data$price / 100000000
  blockTimes  <- rbind(blockTimes,block_n)
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how the author of the `jsonlite` changes the `user-agent` in the [`fromJSON`](https://github.com/jeroen/jsonlite/blob/master/R/fromJSON.R) function. Change the `useragent` variable to the text that you want:

```
h <- curl::new_handle(useragent = paste("jsonlite /", R.version.string))
curl::handle_setheaders(h, Accept = "application/json, text/*, */*")
txt <- curl::curl(url, handle = h)
```

And then call `fromJSON`

`fromJSON(txt)`